# Compute denominator and numerator of irreducible fraction from arbitrary fraction

Tags: pgfmath

I would like to reduce each fraction `i/n` to its irreproducible form (and let's assume i is less than n) and displayed not as a `\frac` fraction but like it is used e.g. in the frame numbers used in latex beamer, i.e. also as `j/m`

When using `pgfmath` the result is a little surprisig and the terms are usual fractions, MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfmath,fp}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/frac}
\newcommand{\fractions}[1]{%
  \foreach \x in {1,...,#1}
    {\pgfmathparse{\x/#1}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\hspace{1em}}
}
\begin{document}
  \fractions{16}
\end{document}
```

which results in 
[image: eWrong fractions]

How can i get that to
`1/16   1/8   3/16   1/4   5/16   3/8   7/16` ... ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use the `gcd()` function to reduce the fractions:

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfmath,pgffor}

\newcommand{\reducedfractions}[1]{%
    \foreach \x in {1,...,#1} {%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numerator}{\x/gcd(\x,#1)}%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\denominator}{#1/gcd(\x,#1)}%
        $\frac{\numerator}{\denominator}\hspace{1em}$%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
  \reducedfractions{16}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `gcd` is not in the pgfmanual, where is the doc on the hidden macros ;-)

Comment: Actually `gcd` is documented in the 3.0.0 version on page 939 :) Despite that - my request included the format `i/n` instead of a fraction itself, but changing your line 8 to `\numerator/\denominator\hspace{1em}` yields my required result - well done.

Answer (score 5):

> [image: fractions]

```
\documentclass [a4paper]{article}
\usepackage [margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xintfrac}
\usepackage{xintexpr}

\newcommand{\fractions}[1]{%
    \xintFor ##1 in {\xintintegers} \do {%
        \xintIrr {##1/#1}\ \ \ 
        \ifnum#1=##1\expandafter\xintBreakFor\fi
    }
}
% Note to the techies: ##1 from \xintintegers is in fact a \numexpr thing;
% generally a \numexpr needs to be prefixed by \the to be used in the xintfrac
% macros, but it is ok if it contains only at most eight tokens. As the macro is
% unlikely to be called as is with #1>99999999, no need to bother, and it is a
% bit more efficient to not do \the.

\newcommand{\mathfractions}[1]{%
    \xintFor ##1 in {\xintintegers} \do {%
        \xintFrac{\xintIrr {##1/#1}}\allowbreak\ 
        \ifnum#1=##1\expandafter\xintBreakFor\fi
    }
}

\begin{document}
\noindent\fractions {420}

\noindent\baselineskip14pt $\mathfractions {420}$\par

\bigskip
\edef\Result{\xinttheexpr reduce (40!*60!*80!/(100!*30!*50!))\relax }
$$\frac{40!*60!*80!}{100!*30!*50!}=\Result=\xintFrac{\Result}$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also: `\xintNumerator` and `\xintDenominator`: `\edef\Result{\xintIrr{whatever/whatever}}`, `\xintNumerator{\Result}`,  `\xintDenominator{\Result}`.

Comment: While this works quite fine, the other solution using `pgfmath` was not only first but is also my favourite one - though that's really just personal favour :)

Comment: @Ronny the question had the `pgfmath` tag, I knew my answer was borderline `;-)`.

Answer (score 4):

Did't know about `gcd`, make it by myself ;-(

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\PGCD}[2]{%
\edef\Num{#1}%
\edef\Den{#2}%
\loop%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\Mod{mod(\Num,\Den)}%
    \ifnum\Mod>0%
    \edef\Num{\Den}%
    \edef\Den{\Mod}%
    \repeat%
    \edef\Pgcd{\Den}%       
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\Num{#1/\Pgcd}%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\Den{#2/\Pgcd}%    
}

\newcommand{\fractions}[1]{%
    \foreach \x in {1,...,#1} {%
        \PGCD{\x}{#1}%
        $\frac{\Num}{\Den}\hspace{1em}$%
    }
}

\begin{document}
\fractions{16}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why all the `\xdef`, when `\edef` is sufficient? Contrary to `\foreach`, `\loop` doesn't perform cycles in groups.

Comment: OK, after I read your comment about groups, I took a look on the definition of `xdef`: \xdef is a synonym for \global\edef, and now I have understood the difference. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

An implementation with the CAS **Sage(math)** and **SageTeX**:

[image]

**I use [arara: sagetex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520683/arara-sage-a-sagemath-rule-for-arara) for compiling.**

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: sagetex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{sagetex}

\begin{document}
\section{In}
\begin{sageblock}
x = 420       # Denominator
MyRange = 222

M = []
for n in range (1,MyRange):
    if x == denominator(n/x):
        M.append('$' + latex(n/x).replace(' ','') + '$')
    else:
        M.append('$' + '\\frac{' + "{}".format(n) + '}{' + "{}".format(x) + '}=' + latex(n/x).replace(' ','') + '$')

MyOut = ', '.join(M)
#print MyOut
\end{sageblock}

\section{Out}
\baselineskip16pt \sagestr{MyOut}
\end{document}
```