# SageTeX: How to run Sage in the command line

Tags: windows, sagetex

The normal run of a tex-file which contains sagetex, say

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage{sagetex} 
\begin{document} 
\sage{2^1234} 
\end{document}
```

is

```
pfdlatex example.tex
sage example.sagetex.sage
pfdlatex example.tex
```

For Linux this should run in exactly this form. 
 
How to do it in the Windows command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage{sagetex} 
\begin{document} 
\sage{2^1234} 
\end{document}
```

be named by  `example.tex`

**0)** Run `pdflatex example.tex` for creating a sage-file

```
example.sagetex.sage
```

**1)** Find out where is your bash-executive `bash.exe` from your Sage-installation, it is something like

```
C:\Programme\SageMath8.9\runtime\bin\bash
```

**2)** Find out where is your "sage-starting-file" `sage` [without extension] (which is getting startet by `bash.exe`, see later), it is something like

```
C:/Programme/SageMath8.9/runtime/opt/sagemath-8.9/sage
```

**3)** Realize which is your current working folder, say

```
 C:\Users\ccc\Desktop\Test\SageTeX
```

**4a)** In the following sage-run you need to change Sage's home directory to your current working folder from No. 3; the sage-command is

```
os.chdir('C:\Users\ccc\Desktop\Test\SageTeX')
```

*BTW: You can check your Sage-Home in a Sage-Shell by typing in `os.getcwd()`*

**4b)** And you have to run your sage-file; the sage-command is

```
load('example.sagetex.sage')
```

**Alltogether in the Windows-cmd:**

```
C:\Programme\SageMath8.9\runtime\bin\bash 
  -l C:/Programme/SageMath8.9/runtime/opt/sagemath-8.9/sage 
       -c "os.chdir('C:\Users\ccc\Desktop\Test\SageTeX');      
                load('example.sagetex.sage')"
```

Use this ***without linebreaks***!

**5)** If all works, Sage will say to you: Run

```
pdflatex example.tex
```

again. After that you will get your sageteXed `example.pdf`.

Comment: Due to that we need a shortcut with @PauloCereda 's  arara. Be wellcome here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520683/arara-sage-a-sagemath-rule-for-arara