# sagetex/arara: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Tags: arara, sagetex

Following up [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/521688/2288), I have the following error in the arara's log file

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes
> in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

when using this `sagetex.yaml` rule

```
!config
# SageTeX-Rule for arara.
#
# Dear Windows-users, please check the paths
# pathToBashExecutive    and    pathToSageStartfile
# due to your Sage-installation!
#
identifier: sagetex
name: SageTeX
authors:
- TeXnician (Author)
- cis (Idea)
arguments: []
commands:
- name: A SageTeX Rule for arara
  command: >
    @{
        pathToBashExecutive = "C:\\Program Files\\SageMath 9.1\\runtime\\bin\\bash";
        pathToSageStartfile = "C:/Program Files/SageMath 9.1/runtime/opt/sagemath-9.1/sage";
        pathOfCurrentWorkingFolder = currentFile().getParent();
        theWindowsCommand = getCommand(pathToBashExecutive, "-l", pathToSageStartfile, "-c", "os.chdir('" + pathOfCurrentWorkingFolder + "'); load('" + getBasename(currentFile()) + ".sagetex.sage')");
        return isWindows(theWindowsCommand, getCommand("sage", getBasename(reference) + ".sagetex.sage"));
       }
```

to compile the following document

```
% arara: lualatex
% arara: sagetex
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}

\begin{document}
    
    Using Sage\TeX, one can use Sage to compute things and put them into
    your \LaTeX{} document. For example, there are
    $\sage{number_of_partitions(1269)}$ integer partitions of $1269$.
    You don't need to compute the number yourself, or even cut and paste
    it from somewhere.
    
    Here's some Sage code:
    \begin{sageblock}
        f(x) = exp(x) * sin(2*x)
    \end{sageblock}
    
    The second derivative of $f$ is
    \[
    \frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}}{\mathrm{d}x^{2}} \sage{f(x)} =
    \sage{diff(f, x, 2)(x)}.
    \]
    Here's a plot of $f$ from $-1$ to $1$:
    \sageplot{plot(f, -1, 1)}
\end{document}
```

Full arara's log file can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/EFiLyvzf).

Comment: This error seems to come from Sage. Have you tried running the programs on the same file one after the other?

Comment: @TeXnician yes I tested the document with sage externally, and it worked fine.

Comment: With tested you mean the same system call, i.e. `C:\Program Files\SageMath 9.1\runtime\bin\bash -l "C:/Program Files/SageMath 9.1/runtime/opt/sagemath-9.1/sage" -c "os.chdir('C:\Users\Diaa\Desktop\Test'); load('testsagetex.sagetex.sage')"`?

Comment: @TeXnician  No, I mean that I first ran lualatex on it. Then, opened sagetex shell to run it on the *.sage file. Finally, I ran lualatex on the tex file without problems. I will give your suggestion a try from the windows command prompt then let you know.

Comment: Well, arara executes exactly that (as seen in the log) because it has been told to (in the rule). This rule is rather suboptimal as well because it is very much tailored towards what cis needed. If your sage is in your PATH you could probably omit all those path handling (not sure on that).

Comment: @TeXnician running `"C:\Program Files\SageMath 9.1\runtime\bin\bash" -l "C:/Program Files/SageMath 9.1/runtime/opt/sagemath-9.1/sage" -c "os.chdir('C:\Users\Diaa\Desktop\Test'); load('testsagetex.sagetex.sage')"` in the cmd window results in [this](https://pastebin.com/tp31HHbs) with the same error, while building the `*.sage` files from the sage shell results in [this](https://pastebin.com/vwKhZu2Y). So, maybe, the cmd syntax needs some tweaks.

Comment: I have no clue what this all does, so I cannot be of any help here. Maybe you should ask someone who knows sage what is to be run.

Comment: I don't know how arara is meant to "enhance your TeX experience", but I'd be happy to add anything it needs to https://github.com/sagemath/sagetex (open an issue there if needed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think (I hope) I've found the solution to the problem.

using: "C:\Users\Pedro Jose\AppData\Local\SageMath 9.1\runtime\bin\bash" -l "C:/Users/Pedro Jose/AppData/Local/SageMath 9.1/runtime/opt/sagemath-9.1/sage" -c "os.chdir('D:/'); load('prueba.sagetex.sage')"

sage works. I think the problem is inside `os.chdir()`, because we have to use `/` instead of `\`. If there is any way to change inside the arara rule "PathOfWorkingFolder" the delimiter `\` to `/` it's probably the rule finaly works.

Here is my test image:

[image]

Edit: Using `\\` on the sage console `os.chdir('d:\\')` works, but in the command line on cmd it doesn't work.

and finaly, I've found the solution. you have to edit thewinndowsCommand and add an `r`just after `"os.chdir(`

Then, that part should be like `"os.chdir(r'"` and that's all. Sagetex rule works.

The full code is:

```
!config
# SageTeX-Rule for arara.
#
# Dear Windows-users, please check the paths
# pathToBashExecutive    and    pathToSageStartfile
# due to your Sage-installation!
#
identifier: sagetex
name: SageTeX
authors:
- TeXnician (Author)
- cis (Idea)
- Pedro J (final fix)
arguments: []
commands:
- name: A SageTeX Rule for arara
  command: >
    @{
        pathToBashExecutive = "C:\\Program Files\\SageMath 9.1\\runtime\\bin\\bash";
        pathToSageStartfile = "C:/Program Files/SageMath 9.1/runtime/opt/sagemath-9.1/sage";
        pathOfCurrentWorkingFolder = currentFile().getParent();
        theWindowsCommand = getCommand(pathToBashExecutive, "-l", pathToSageStartfile, "-c", "os.chdir(r'" + pathOfCurrentWorkingFolder + "'); load('" + getBasename(currentFile()) + ".sagetex.sage')");
        return isWindows(theWindowsCommand, getCommand("sage", getBasename(reference) + ".sagetex.sage"));
       }
```

Comment: I can confirm that without the extra `r` I get @Diaa's problem, and with it everything works fine. Good find, great!